# Laravel y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito apoyo para mostrar datos de una variable a través de  `js`.

Tengo esa función en `JavaScript` y necesito llamarla desde `html` y que me muestre el `select` con la data que hay en BD.

De esa forma lo hago en `html` y funciona pero ya en `js` no.

```
const DIVINT = document.querySelector('#PROBAR');
function mostra(){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `<label>Ocupación actual:</label><br>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="DEPA">Ocupación actual:</label><br>
        <select class = 'form-control' name="Profesion" required>
            <option value="">Selecionar Ocupación ...</option>
            <?php foreach ($p as $i) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i["id"] ?>">
                <?php echo $i["descrip"]; ?>
                </option>
            <?php }?>
         </select>
    </div>`;
    DIVINT.appendChild(div);
}
```

El formulario está diseñado de la siguiente manera;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que al ingresar un numero en el input se me cree una pregunta con nuevos campos y estos nuevos campos traigan información de la base de datos, ya me funciona la creación de los mismos, pero menos el cargado de información en los select.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se comprende bien lo que requieres, agrega mas contexto editando tu pregunta. Necesitas que el select este disponible al cargar la pagina? o después de algún evento?

Comment: Hola Misael, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: estaba mal escrita la funcion ya esta correguida esa funcion es la que necesito que en el select traiga los datos estoy trabajando en un proyecto de laravel

Comment: Ten cuidado con esas combinaciones de comillas simples y dobles, puede ser lo que te está causando el problema. Aquí por ejemplo `<option value="<?php echo $i["id"] ?>">` estás interrumpiendo la construcción del `value`. En su liugar debería quedar algo así `<option value="<?php echo $i['id'] ?>">` igual aquí `<?php echo $i['descrip']; ?>`. Prueba y comenta.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es usar `ajax` o `fetch` para consultar la información al backend, retornar el `HTML` ya maquetado y entregarlo desde `JS` a la vista en `HTML`, así mantienes separado el código del backend del código del frontend...

Pero de no ser posible, puedes usar algo como esto en el archivo `PHP` o `HTML` que ya tienes:

```
<?php
//Maquetar el HTML desde PHP...
$html = '
    <label>Ocupación actual:</label><br>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control" name="Profesion" required> 
    <option value="">Selecionar Ocupación... </option>
';
foreach ($p as $i) { 
    $html .= '<option value="'.$i["id"].'">'.$i["descrip"].'</option>';
}
$html .= '
    </select>
    </div>
';

//Ejecutar el script desde la misma pagina
echo "<script>
    const DIVINT = document.querySelector('#PROBAR');
    function mostra() {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        //Mostrar el HTML solo cuando es necesario
        div.innerHTML = ".$html.";
        DIVINT.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>";
?>
```

No estoy seguro si funciona ya que se debe probar dentro de tu proyecto, pero es lo más cercano a una solución.

Prueba y comenta.

Comment: no funciona el div se crea pero la variable no se imprime

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para incluir el `script` dentro de `php`. Nótese que también cambia el `echo` por una concatenación de la variable en `div.innerHTML = ".$html.";`

Comment: no funciona ☹️el div se crea así: <div><!-- <?php echo $html; ?> --></div>